# What is wrong here...? I am new to this and I am trying to set up a TabHost

Tags: android, eclipse

[My Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDjPB.png)
This is just one of the classes. 
This deals with TabHosts and trying to figure out how it works...?

```
package com.example.basicrecipes;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

public class **ERROR HERE-->** RecipeNew extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

TabHost _tabHost;
Resources _res;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipe_tabs);

    _tabHost = getTabHost();
    _res = getResources();
    _tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    TabHost.TabSpec _tabSpec;

    _tabSpec = _tabHost.newTabSpec("recipes").setIndicator("Recipe", _res.getDrawable(R.drawable.recipe_tabs)).setContent(new Intent(this, RecipeEntry.class));
    _tabHost.addTab(_tabSpec);

    _tabSpec = _tabHost.newTabSpec("ingredients").setIndicator("Ingredients", _res.getDrawable(R.drawable.recipe_tab_ingredients)).setContent(new Intent(this, RecipeIngredients.class));
    _tabHost.addTab(_tabSpec);

    for(int i=0; i<_tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        _tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    }

    _tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1);
    _tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

**ERROR HERE-->** }


**ERROR HERE-->** public void onTabChanged(String tabI(d){
    for (int i=0; i<_tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++){
        _tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    }
    _tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(_tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

}

**ERROR HERE-->** }
```

So I have these errors here and I do not know why it keeps bringing up these errors...?

So what is going on... Please Help???

Comment: `public void onTabChanged(String tabI(d){` contains a none valid parenthesis, Checkout `tabI(d)`. Not a valid java identifier.

Comment: Got it! Thank You :)

Comment: It should look like this: `public void onTabChanged(String tabId){`

Comment: Did this solve your whole problem?

Comment: Well in the image I attached The TabActivity seems to be depreciated...?

Comment: Yes, it is deprecated. You should use [support libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) or look at more modern UI features.